# Unable To Increase UrlImageView Size! (Android)

Tags: java, android-layout, android, android-xml

I have a customized imageWiew (UrlImageView) which is a thumbnail which is being pulled from YouTube via JSON. It's acting VERY unusual though...

I'm familiar with the usual culprits - not setting an android:scaleType (fillXY or centerCrop) or perhaps forgetting match_parent - however I've tried many combinations  of of these. Nothing seems to make the thumbnail in the app larger.

This lead me to think... hmmm - perhaps I'm getting  a tiny thumbnail from YouTube! Nope...  It's using and returning hqdefault:

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/jXE6G9CYcJs/hqdefault.jpg
```

I've really been struggling with this for a while and I think I need to figure out a way to control/modify/tweak whatever layout or layout parameter is shown here with the layout framework developer option turned on:

[image]

I'm thinking it's either:

A. An incorrect combination of layout_width and layout_height parameters (perhaps a parent affecting a child in a manner I'm unaware of)

B.  A conflict between java and  XML parameters

C. Something obvious (which I accidentally overlooked)

D. A modification or difference between my source and the sourced I used as an example to build what  I have (the entire package is available at this link - it should be helpful if someone wants to download it and nail it  down quickly)

http://blog.blundell-apps.com/show-youtube-user-videos-in-a-listview/

E.  Something  abnormal/unusual (I'm doing most of testing on a device with a 5 inch screen - it's a Star N920e [strange - eh? I know... but the development has to be done on this device. I'll try any solutions in the emulator to avoid any twilight zone issues - but I just want to be clear that's what I did most of my testing on thus far  - which may have been a mistake. Given that - feel free to suggest  and vote on your favorite responses - let's see what floats to the top on this one!])

---

P.S.

Pardon the debatably long post - I think I have parent/child issues going on plus the tutorial uses 2 xml files to  instantiate everything so I included that as well as the java I'm using. I apologize - but I think it's necessary.

Also if you want to download the sample project  - then plugin what I've done (wrong) the source can be found directly here:

https://github.com/blundell/YouTubeUserFeed

### home.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/darkgrey"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:background="#AAFFFFFF" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" 
            android:orientation="vertical" >

                 <com.example.project.ui.widget.VideosListView
            android:id="@+id/videosListView"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="50dip"
                android:layout_height="50dip"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:background="@color/darkgrey"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/home_up_btn" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/footer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dip"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                 >

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="30dip"
                    android:layout_height="30dip"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:src="@drawable/scroll_lt_arrow" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="30dip"
                    android:layout_height="30dip"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:src="@drawable/scroll_rt_arrow" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

### list_item_user_video.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

         <com.example.project.ui.widget.UrlImageView
        android:id="@+id/userVideoThumbImageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:contentDescription="YouTube video thumbnail"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/userVideoTitleTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="5dip"
            android:text="Video Title Not Found"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/fav_up_btn1"
            android:layout_width="27dp"
            android:layout_height="27dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@drawable/fav_up_btn1"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/userVideouploaderTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="5dip"
            android:textColor="@color/verylightgrey"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/userVideoviewsTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/userVideouploaderTextView"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

### JAVA:

```
public class UrlImageView extends LinearLayout {

    private Context mContext;
    private Drawable mDrawable;
    private ProgressBar mSpinner;
    private ImageView mImage;

    public UrlImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public UrlImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    /**
     * First time loading of the LoaderImageView
     * Sets up the LayoutParams of the view, you can change these to
     * get the required effects you want
     */
    private void init(final Context context) {
        mContext = context;

        mImage = new ImageView(mContext);
        mImage.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        mImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        mSpinner = new ProgressBar(mContext);
        mSpinner.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        mSpinner.setIndeterminate(true);

        addView(mSpinner);
        addView(mImage);
    }


    public void setImageDrawable(final String imageUrl) {
        mDrawable = null;
        mSpinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    mDrawable = getDrawableFromUrl(imageUrl);
                    imageLoadedHandler.sendEmptyMessage(RESULT_OK);
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    imageLoadedHandler.sendEmptyMessage(RESULT_CANCELED);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    imageLoadedHandler.sendEmptyMessage(RESULT_CANCELED);
                }
            };
        }.start();
    }


    private final Handler imageLoadedHandler = new Handler(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
            case RESULT_OK:
                mImage.setImageDrawable(mDrawable);
                mImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                mSpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                break;
            case RESULT_CANCELED:
            default:

                break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });


    private static Drawable getDrawableFromUrl(final String url) throws IOException, MalformedURLException {
        return Drawable.createFromStream(((java.io.InputStream) new java.net.URL(url).getContent()), "name");
    }

}
```

### Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `android:adjustViewBounds` to true. You might also want to adjust `layout_width` to `match_parent`

Comment: I did... still no luck

Comment: I'm having a few other issues with this build as well... mind taking a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20913058/android-xml-layout-parameters-do-not-function-as-expected

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20911739/adding-a-textview-to-drag-and-drop-interface-android-java